# In UIView implementation, under what condition is drawRect: being called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I understand that calling `setNeedsDisplay` would invoke `drawRect:` but I want to ask what could lead to a view calling `setNeedsDisplay` (of course except when you want to call it explicitly), e.g.

- Does resizing a view call `drawRect` on itself? How about its subviews?

Answer (score 4):

It's called whenever the view is needed to be redrawn. So that will be when an internal flag is set, which `setNeedsDisplay` will set.

Of course, though, doing other things might cause `setNeedsDisplay` to be called. For instance if you're using the content mode of `UIViewContentModeRedraw` then as per the docs:

> **UIViewContentModeRedraw**
>
> Redisplays the view when the bounds change by invoking the setNeedsDisplay method.

You'll get a `drawRect:` happen after bounds change if using this content mode.

Apart from that I can't really think of any other methods that have the side effect of calling `setNeedsDisplay` but there might well be some more.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I still don't know what condition will make the view redrawing itself. Does resizing a view call drawRect on itself? How about its subviews? How about just moving the view 1px to the left?

Comment: "Redisplays the view when the bounds change" - if content mode is `UIViewContentModeRedraw`. That's your answer to resizing / moving. As for subviews - no they won't cause their parent to need a redraw.

Comment: Does that mean other `contentMode` won't trigger `drawRect` when the size changes? Sorry for asking so many question but I don't quite get it.

Comment: Correct that `drawRect` won't be triggered with other `contentMode`s. Well, to be precise, `setNeedsDisplay` will not be called.